# Azure Portal error creating Blob Container in Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I just created an Azure App Service to host a web application and I want to turn on application logging. I have enabled it in the app itself.

Using the Azure Portal, I tried to configure the app for logging under Diagnostics Logging, but after I created a new storage account to hold the logging blob, it won't let me create a container with Blob Access in the storage account. I keep getting "Error: error" from the portal. I also tried creating a File Container and it failed with the same error.

Why can't I create a Blob Container (or other container) in this Storage Account?

- Storage Account was created through the App Service Diagnostics Logging Blade.
- Storage Account is a Standard, Locally Redundant account

**Update 08/11/2017:**

Just to be clear, here are the exact steps I took to get to this point:

1. Created new App Service with its own Resource Group and created a new Service Plan at the Free Pricing Tier.
2. Then from Visual Studio, I published my Web API (ASP.NET Core, not that it matters.)
3. From the Azure Portal, clicked on Diagnostics Logs (for the App Service), turned on Application Logging (Blob), clicked on Storage Settings, chose Add Storage Account. Created as Standard, Locally Redundant and in the same Resource Group as I created for the App Service.

   - Incidentally, from this Storage Accounts blade, I cannot see any other Storage Accounts in my subscription, even though I added one manually to the same Resource Group.
4. Then I selected the Storage Account and clicked on + Container to create a new container.
5. I entered the container name, and in this blade, the drop-down is empty. Nothing there to select what kind of permissions this container should have.
6. Yesterday, when I could click the Create button anyway, I would get the Error Notification popup in the Notifications section.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in your post. But I can't reproduced the issue. I can create container for the storage account which created for diagnostics logging on my side.  Please open Activity log of your storage service and query the detail information of the error.

Comment: I checked the storage account Activity Logs for the last 24 hours and I do not see any errors logged there. In fact, the only thing logged was today and it is a ListKeys log. I checked my notifications and that's where the errors showed up: `Failed to create storage container 'myblob'. Error: error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I retraced my steps as I was editing the original post, and when I clicked Create today, it worked!! I am not sure why it wasn't working yesterday - maybe it really wasn't ready to add anything to the Storage Account. I guess it just took a lot longer than I thought even though there was no indication that it was still creating.

So, problem resolved itself. (I hate that though, because it means that I don't understand why.) :/

Comment: I'm having the same error right now: `Failed to create storage container 'myblob'. Error: error` When trying to create a storage container. Before this I created blob storage and could only see blobs (not file, table, queue). I'm doing a lot of deleting and recreating while I experiment with this so I'm just putting it down to that. It seems it's a but unstable